# Add multiple events to Google calendar with button

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I am trying to make a button for website visitors as "Add to Calendar" that sends multiple events to calendar. I found the solution for one event with button and the URI. If I make a loop it means that user need to approve the event as many times as events but how can I send multiple events?
I have searched for Google API Batch request but I'm confused about how it can create one request for all the events!?

This is the code I have made with Google samples but only works in terminal 0_o:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';


define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'Google Calendar API PHP Quickstart');
define('CREDENTIALS_PATH', '~/.credentials/calendar-php-quickstart.json');
define('CLIENT_SECRET_PATH', __DIR__ . '/client_secret.json');
// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/calendar-php-quickstart.json
define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(
  Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY)
));

if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
  throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
}

/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
function getClient() {
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
  $client->setScopes(SCOPES);
  $client->setAuthConfigFile(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
  $client->setAccessType('offline');

  // Load previously authorized credentials from a file.
  $credentialsPath = expandHomeDirectory(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
  if (file_exists($credentialsPath)) {
    $accessToken = file_get_contents($credentialsPath);
  } else {
    // Request authorization from the user.
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
    print 'Enter verification code: ';
    $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

    // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
    $accessToken = $client->authenticate($authCode);

    // Store the credentials to disk.
    if(!file_exists(dirname($credentialsPath))) {
      mkdir(dirname($credentialsPath), 0700, true);
    }
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, $accessToken);
    printf("Credentials saved to %s\n", $credentialsPath);
  }
  $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

  // Refresh the token if it's expired.
  if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->refreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, $client->getAccessToken());
  }
  return $client;
}

/**
 * Expands the home directory alias '~' to the full path.
 * @param string $path the path to expand.
 * @return string the expanded path.
 */
function expandHomeDirectory($path) {
  $homeDirectory = getenv('HOME');
  if (empty($homeDirectory)) {
    $homeDirectory = getenv("HOMEDRIVE") . getenv("HOMEPATH");
  }
  return str_replace('~', realpath($homeDirectory), $path);
}

$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
  'summary' => 'Google I/O 2015',
  'location' => '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
  'description' => 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
  'start' => array(
    'dateTime' => '2015-05-28T09:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
  ),
  'end' => array(
    'dateTime' => '2015-05-28T17:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
  ),
  // 'recurrence' => array(
  //   'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
  // ),
  // 'attendees' => array(
  //   array('email' => 'lpage@example.com'),
  //   array('email' => 'sbrin@example.com'),
  // ),
  'reminders' => array(
    'useDefault' => FALSE,
    'overrides' => array(
      array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 24 * 60),
      array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 10),
    ),
  ),
));


$event1 = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
  'summary' => 'Google I/O 2015',
  'location' => '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
  'description' => 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
  'start' => array(
    'dateTime' => '2015-05-28T09:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
  ),
  'end' => array(
    'dateTime' => '2015-05-28T17:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
  ),
  // 'recurrence' => array(
  //   'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
  // ),
  // 'attendees' => array(
  //   array('email' => 'lpage@example.com'),
  //   array('email' => 'sbrin@example.com'),
  // ),
  'reminders' => array(
    'useDefault' => FALSE,
    'overrides' => array(
      array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 24 * 60),
      array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 10),
    ),
  ),
));


$Events = array($event, $event1);

addTwo($Events);

function addTwo($event){

// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();

$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
$calendarId = 'primary';
foreach ($event as $key => $value) {
  $event = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $value);
  printf('Event created: %s\n', $event->htmlLink);
}

}

?>
```

Comment: Welcome to stack for us to help you we need to see your code and what you have tried.

Comment: Thanks. I have added my code into the question.

Comment: This looks like a similar question in this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439104/php-google-calendar-api-adding-multiple-events-at-once).

Comment: @noogui yes, but even that one doesn't have a approved answer! The only answer in the other threat says there is no way to add multiple events in one request. 
I thought batch request is to make multiple action in one request but I just don't know how to use it and I couldn't find a good example.